# Strange issue when calling same piece of code in multiple places in one template

Tags: django

I am facing a strange issue. I have two method in a model. `get_delivery_taxes` and `get_subtotal_taxes` as shown below:

```
def get_delivery_taxes(self):
    delivery_tax_list = []
    if self.modifiers:
        if self.modifiers.get('Taxation', None):
            for tax in self.modifiers.get('Taxation'):
                if tax.get('delivery_tax', None):
                    delivery_tax_dict = tax.get('delivery_tax')

                    delivery_tax_amount = delivery_tax_dict['amount']
                    delivery_tax_dict['amount'] = Money(delivery_tax_amount, settings.DEFAULT_CURRENCY)

                    delivery_tax_list.append(delivery_tax_dict)
    return delivery_tax_list


def get_subtotal_taxes(self):
    subtotal_tax_list = []

    if self.modifiers:
        if self.modifiers.get('Taxation', None):
            for tax in self.modifiers.get('Taxation'):
                subtotal_tax_dict = None
                if tax.get('subtotal_tax', None):
                    subtotal_tax_dict = tax.get('subtotal_tax')

                    subtotal_tax_amount = subtotal_tax_dict['amount']

                    subtotal_tax_dict['amount'] = Money(subtotal_tax_amount, settings.DEFAULT_CURRENCY)

                    subtotal_tax_list.append(subtotal_tax_dict)
    return subtotal_tax_list
```

Those two methods are then used by these below methods to calculate their totals.

```
def get_subtotal_tax_price(self):
    subtotal_tax_price = 0
    for sub_tax_price in self.get_subtotal_taxes():
        subtotal_tax_price = subtotal_tax_price + sub_tax_price['amount']
    return subtotal_tax_price


def get_delivery_tax_price(self):
    delvry_tax_amount = 0
    for del_tax_price in self.get_delivery_taxes():
        delvry_tax_amount = delvry_tax_amount + del_tax_price['amount']
    return delvry_tax_amount
```

A final total is calculated using above two methods as below.

```
def get_order_final_total(self):
        subtotal = self.get_order_subtotal_price()
        subtotal_taxes = self.get_subtotal_tax_price()

        devilery_charges = self.get_order_delivery_charges_price()

        devilery_charges_taxes = self.get_delivery_tax_price()

        order_total = subtotal + subtotal_taxes + devilery_charges + devilery_charges_taxes
        return order_total
```

In my template, I use them as below:

```
{% for tax_dict in object.get_delivery_taxes %}
...
{% endfor %}

{% for tax_dict in object.get_subtotal_taxes %}
...
{% endfor %}


{{object.get_order_final_total}}
```

Doing this was working fine until I made changes to first two methods( get_delivery_taxes and get_subtotal_taxes). I added:

```
subtotal_tax_amount = subtotal_tax_dict['amount']

subtotal_tax_dict['amount'] = Money(subtotal_tax_amount, settings.DEFAULT_CURRENCY)
```

And:

```
subtotal_tax_amount = subtotal_tax_dict['amount']

subtotal_tax_dict['amount'] = Money(subtotal_tax_amount, settings.DEFAULT_CURRENCY)
```

I get this error:

```
File ".............\models.py", line 1251, in get_order_final_total
    devilery_charges_taxes = self.get_delivery_tax_price()
  File ".............\models.py", line 1240, in get_delivery_tax_price
    for del_tax_price in self.get_delivery_taxes():
  File ".............\models.py", line 1180, in get_delivery_taxes
    delivery_tax_dict['amount'] = Money(delivery_tax_amount, settings.DEFAULT_CURRENCY)
  File "C:\Users\user\Envs\myproj_py_38\lib\site-packages\moneyed\classes.py", line 83, in __init__
    amount = Decimal(str(amount))
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]
```

But when I remove

`{% for tax_dict in object.get_delivery_taxes %} ... {% endfor %}`

AND

`{% for tax_dict in object.get_subtotal_taxes %} ... {% endfor %}`

OR

`{{object.get_order_final_total}}`

It no longer throws the error.

That `Money()` is from `from moneyed import Money`

Can anyone please point out what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some hours on this I finally found the cause of this error.

As two methods access same code and try to change same dictionary it gives error since one the calls has already made a change(in this case, converting string 'amount' to `Money()`). The second call tries to update the same dict value assuming it is a string while it is actually `Money()`.

So the solution is to copy dictionary and make changes to that like this below:

```
if tax.get('subtotal_tax', None):
    subtotal_tax_dict = tax.get('subtotal_tax')
    subtotal_tax_dict_copy = subtotal_tax_dict.copy()

    subtotal_tax_dict_copy['amount'] = Money(subtotal_tax_dict_copy['amount'], settings.DEFAULT_CURRENCY)

    subtotal_tax_list.append(subtotal_tax_dict_copy)
```

This gives you a new dictionary and then you can make changes to its value without affecting the original dict.